# Does Safari/Webview in iOS8 support WebAudio recording?

Tags: mobile-safari, audio-recording, ios8, web-audio-api

I'm gonna guess "no" as I can't find any reference on the internet to it.  I checked the API diffs but that doesn't seem to cover javascript.  Not sure where to look next...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you mean live input recording?  Then no.  You can record web audio output thru record.js or offline audio context, but no webrtc/live input.